# intuition behind finding inverse of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

[image: matrices]

NOTE: I was not able to upload the matrix in the  normal way so I created the image and i think it is easy to view it now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\B&C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X&Y\\Z&W\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$$
Now you have 4 equations to solve:
$$\begin{align}
AX &= I\\
AY &= 0\\
BX+CZ &= 0\\
BY+CW &= I
\end{align}$$
So, from (1) and (2) you get $X=A^{-1}$ and $Y=0$ and other results follow similarly.